# How do I install Maven with Yum?

Tags: maven-2, yum

I'm trying *not* to learn much about either yum or maven.  I've inherited this code and I don't want to spend more time than I have to in this environment.

I've got yum.  My installation "has" ("is attached too"? "knows about"?) two repos: the Amazon one and JPackage, which I understand is something of a standard.  (Actually, each of those repositories consists of two sub-repositories, but I don't think that's causing the problem.)

When I asked yum to install maven2, it declined, saying it had never heard of maven2.

When I asked yum to install maven2 *ignoring Amazon*, it does so, but it installs Maven 2.0.9, which is fairly old.  The actual pom.xml I have requires a higher version.

When I Google for Maven repositories I get repositories that Maven can use to build other things, not repositories that Yum can use to install Maven.  (I did find a repository containing thing that let Maven build Yum.  I think Google is mocking me at this point.)

So, all I need is the repo *file* that points to a repo that contains whatever I need to install Maven 2.2.1.

If it weren't for all these labor-saving devices, I could probably get some work done.

Answer (score 236):

Icarus answered a very similar question for me. Its not using "yum", but should still work for your purposes. Try,

```
wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.0.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz
```

basically just go to the [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). Find the version of maven you want. The file type and use the mirror for the wget statement above.

Afterwards the process is easy

1. Run the wget command from the dir you want to extract maven too.
2. run the following to extract the tar,

   ```
   tar xvf apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz
   ```
3. move maven to /usr/local/apache-maven

   ```
   mv apache-maven-3.0.5  /usr/local/apache-maven
   ```
4. Next add the env variables to your ~/.bashrc file

   ```
   export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven
   export M2=$M2_HOME/bin 
   export PATH=$M2:$PATH
   ```
5. Execute these commands

   source ~/.bashrc

6:. Verify everything is working with the following command

```
    mvn -version
```

Comment: Thanks! the best maven i could get via `jpackage` was `maven.noarchtbd` which was `v1.1` or `maven2` which was `v2.0.4` ... your alternate instructions helped a lot to get me to maven v3 :)

Comment: These instructions work.  But why oh why can't they just put maven in the package repository with all the other packages so that people don't have to jump through these hoops?

Comment: @aroth probably because there are those that consider Maven anathema

Comment: just replace the path you pass to `wget` with one you get from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @Ali Does Apache provide a way to use their domain name rather than the mirrors domain name ?

Comment: @JosephLust those are the very most insane people walking on earth

Comment: I found `export PATH=$M2:$PATH` to have corrupted my bash.. couldn't able to run any command like `ls` etc. so had to restore the ~/.bashrc and used `export PATH=$PATH:$M2:`[Note the change of $M2 after $PATH] to get the bash working. Hope this helps others, if needed.

Comment: On AWS Cloud9, this works too, except you have to add `sudo` in front of `mv apache-maven-3.0.5  /usr/local/apache-maven`.

Comment: It looks like the host mirror for the wget is now down. This location worked for me:
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 123):

You can add maven to the yum libraries like this:

```
wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
```

Now you *can* install maven like this:

```
yum install apache-maven
```

Once done, maven 3 will be installed and `mvn -version` will show you which version you've got - I had 3.2.1.

This worked perfectly for me on CentOS 6 with one exception. It installed OpenJDK 1.6 and made it the default Java version, even though I'd already manually installed JDK 8 (possibly *because* I'd manually installed it). To change it back use `alternatives`:

```
alternatives --config java
alternatives --config javac
```

and choose the correct version.

Comment: As described [in this forum](http://blog.gluster.org/2013/08/yum-install-maven-yes-you-can/), `epel-$releasever` in the downloaded `.repo` file needs to be replaced with `epel-6`, or else `yum install apache-maven` will fail with error 404.

Comment: Even replacing epel-$releasever with epel-6 fails with 404:
     http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6/i386/repodata/194b1dce25e9483ae3ce34f3e4f807770dd77705-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"

Comment: it's possible to install a specific (e.g. 3.0.1) version with this approach?

Comment: I was able to get it working fine with this entry in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo` repo file: `baseurl=https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6/$basearch/`

Comment: `alternatives --config java`

Comment: This one is missing [STEP 2 - replace `$releasever` with `6`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34168861/432903) which is [described in another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34168861/432903)

Comment: I did as you said in CentOS 7, it works great, thanks. Just wondering that why this approach will change the jdk and how to prevent this problem?

Comment: When I ran the maven installer there was no JDK or JRE installed via yum. So to all intents and purposes there was a missing dependency. I suspect it automatically installed the minimum version required as specified by the maven package. To stop it happening, install your JDK of preference first via yum.

Comment: `http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`

Answer (score 70):

For future reference and for simplicity sake for the lazy people out there that don't want much explanations but just run things and make it work asap:

1) `sudo wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo`

2) `sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo`

3) `sudo yum install -y apache-maven`

4) `mvn --version`

Hope you enjoyed this copy & paste session.

Comment: This sounded like it would work perfectly except received this error: http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6/x86_64/apache-maven-3.3.3-4.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

Don't know if the repo is temporarily down or permanently down.

Comment: @advocate I just created another server instance and run the exact commands as described and worked like a charm. sorry for the late reply, but looks like it still working. cheers.

Comment: why would you replace the symbol with a hardcoded version?

Comment: @Kate which symbol?

Comment: I guess @Kate means `$releasever`.

Comment: This worked for me without step 2, but it wants to isntall jdk 1.7 even though I already have a 1.8 installed

Comment: While this works well, dchen hasn't updated their repo since 3.3.x.

Comment: It installs Java 7 and set it as default, so it brokes the further process for me :(

Answer (score 25):

```
yum install -y yum-utils

yum-config-manager --add-repo http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo

yum-config-manager --enable epel-apache-maven

yum install -y apache-maven
```

**for JVM developer, this is a SDK manager for all the tool you need.**

https://sdkman.io/

Install sdkman:

```
yum install -y zip unzip

curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Install Maven:

```
sdk install maven
```

Comment: 2023. This is not working anymore `No package apache-maven available.`

Comment: 2023 working, thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

For those of you that are looking for a way to install Maven in 2018:

```
$ sudo yum install maven
```

is supported these days.

Comment: Works for me on Amazon Linux 2 (March 2019).

Comment: Yes, but I installed Java 11 on Amazon Linux 2, and then sudo yum install maven. It installed Java 8 and replaced my instance of 11. Somebody wasn't thinking...

Comment: thank you, this answer should go to top of the list

Answer (score 12):

I've just learned of a handy packaging tool called [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) recently. Stumbling upon this question I thought I might give it a try. Turns out, after reading @OrwellHindenberg's answer, it's easy to package maven into an RPM with fpm.

```
yum install -y gcc make rpm-build ruby-devel rubygems
gem install fpm
```

create a project directory and layout the directory structure of the package

```
mkdir maven-build
cd maven-build
mkdir -p etc/profile.d opt
```

create a file that we'll install to `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh`, we'll store this under the newly created *etc/profile.d* directory as *maven.sh*, with the following contents

```
export M3_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0
export M3=$M3_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M3:$PATH
```

download and unpack the [latest maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) in the *opt* directory

```
wget http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/maven/maven-3/3.1.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.tar.gz -C opt
```

finally, build the RPM

```
fpm -n maven-3.1.0 -s dir -t rpm etc opt
```

Now you can install maven through rpm

```
$ rpm -Uvh maven-3.1.0-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:maven-3.1.0            ########################################### [100%]
```

and viola

```
$ which mvn
/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/mvn
```

not quite *yum* but closer to home ;)

Comment: I went with maven 3 for my purposes, but just as easy to package maven v2.

Comment: One other note, you'll have to logout / login for the _/etc/profile.d/maven.sh_ script to take.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. BTW. You can also type `exec bash` (assuming you are using bash).

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to install it with yum? There's plenty other possibilities:

- Grab the binary from http://maven.apache.org/download.html and put it in your /usr/bn
- If you are using Eclipse you can get the m2eclipse plugin (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) which bundles a version of maven

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that in about the next 15 minutes if I cannot figure out a better way.  The reason I'm hesitant is that Yum is actually a good product *if it knows about everything that's installed*.  Otherwise, not so much.  I'm sure Maven is also a good product, at doing something I don't need done, keeping library versions up to date.  The system I'm tending to uses it as a build system, a task it is a little better at than a shell script and about a third as good as Make, circa 1989.  Grrr.

Comment: Well, if they only maintained maven2 up to version 2.0.7 in the jPackage repository, then you can either deal with that version, install by hand or you could create an RPM from the sources at maven.apache.org and install this with yum. But you already stated that you don't want to spend more time then necessary with this, so I think option 1 would suit your situation the most

Comment: Question is about installing it with yum.

Comment: Both of these answers do not answer the question. The real answer should be about some yum repo available that contains the maven3 (latest stable?) packages.

Comment: `/usr/bn` or `/usr/bin`? What about other directories such as `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I went through on Amazon/AWS EMR v5. (Adapted from the previous answers), to have **Maven** and **Java8**.

```
sudo wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
sudo alternatives --config java
```

pick Java8

```
sudo alternatives --config javac
```

pick Java8

Now, if you run:

```
mvn -version
```

You should get:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.38.amzn1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: “unix"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maven is packaged for Fedora since mid 2014, so it is now pretty easy. Just type

```
sudo dnf install maven
```

Now test the installation, just run maven in a random directory

```
mvn
```

And it will fail, because you did not specify a goal, e.g. `mvn package`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.102 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-14T13:45:00+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build

[...]
```

Comment: a silly gotcha is that maven is not `maven` executable, but rather `mvn`...

Answer (score 1):

Not just `mvn`, for any util, you can find out yourself by giving `yum whatprovides {command_name}`