# how to compile cygnus 1.1.0 from sources and update cygnus 0.13?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I follow the guide doing this steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git

cd fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common

mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single

cp target/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext 

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.telefonica.iot -DartifactId=cygnus-common -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false

cp target/classes/cygnus-flume-ng /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng

cd ../cygnus-ngsi

mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single
```

but in the last step compiling cygnus-ngsi I'm getting the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cygnus-ngsi 1.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-common:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cygnus-ngsi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cygnus-ngsi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ cygnus-ngsi ---
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /home/FiWare-VM014cen-Admin/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-ngsi/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus-common/1.1.0/cygnus-common-1.1.0.jar; zip file is empty
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.953 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-07T07:56:53-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project cygnus-ngsi: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus-common/1.1.0/cygnus-common-1.1.0.jar; zip file is empty
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I installed maven following this guide with the recommended version in the docs(3.2.5) [How do I install Maven with Yum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532928/how-do-i-install-maven-with-yum)

Flume is already installed from cygnus 0.13 that is what i want to upgrade to 1.1.0

I also tried most of the answers from this topic [Maven : error in opening zip file when running maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600028/maven-error-in-opening-zip-file-when-running-maven)

**Edit 1** (compiling cygnus-common)

```
[root@PAPELclub-VM014cen-Prod cygnus-common]# mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cygnus-common 1.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/FiWare-VM014cen-Admin/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to /home/FiWare-VM014cen-Admin/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/FiWare-VM014cen-Admin/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Terminado (killed)
```

y el resultado en target:

```
[root@PAPELclub-VM014cen-Prod cygnus-common]# ls -all target/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 jun  8 04:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 jun  8 04:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jun  8 04:49 archive-tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jun  8 04:49 classes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 jun  8 04:50 cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jun  8 04:49 generated-sources
```

I don't know why is terminating it I already give more memory to de jvm of maven as the documentation said:

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

**Edit 2**
With the compiled files in the right places

> /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng

all with the correct rights (777) I'm getting the following error when running with this command:

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_hist.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Error:

```
[root@PAPELclub-VM014cen-Prod conf]# /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_hist.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_hist.conf -n cygnusagent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.164CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=main | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[166] : Starting Cygnus, version 1.1.0.6442a45c568e21908b9455bebe378bc7194489bb
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.789CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=main | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[277] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.793CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=start | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.820CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=run | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_hist.conf
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.841CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.842CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.843CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.849CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[930] : Added sinks: ckan-sink Agent: cygnusagent
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.850CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.850CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.850CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.850CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.851CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.851CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.852CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.852CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.860CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.860CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=addProperty | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.886CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=validateConfiguration | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnusagent]
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.887CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=loadChannels | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[150] : Creating channels
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.913CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=create | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory[40] : Creating instance of channel ckan-channel type memory
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.923CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=loadChannels | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[205] : Created channel ckan-channel
time=2016-06-14T06:51:34.925CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=create | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory[39] : Creating instance of source http-source, type org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.023CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=configure | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[153] : Startup completed
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.100CDT | lvl=ERROR | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=configureInterceptors | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor[113] : Builder class not found. Exception follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorBuilderFactory.newInstance(InterceptorBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:109)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configure(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:353)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.121CDT | lvl=ERROR | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=loadSources | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[366] : Source http-source has been removed due to an error during configuration
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Interceptor.Builder not found.
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:114)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configure(ChannelProcessor.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:353)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorBuilderFactory.newInstance(InterceptorBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:109)
    ... 12 more
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.122CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=create | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory[40] : Creating instance of sink: ckan-sink, type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.144CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=getConfiguration | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[119] : Channel ckan-channel connected to [ckan-sink]
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.164CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=startAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{ckan-sink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@38b60c0 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{ckan-channel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: ckan-channel}} }
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.164CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=startAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[145] : Starting Channel ckan-channel
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.371CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=register | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[110] : Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel, registered successfully.
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.372CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=start | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel started
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.372CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=startAllComponents | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[173] : Starting Sink ckan-sink
time=2016-06-14T06:51:35.790CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=main | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[286] : Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.030CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.060CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : jetty-6.1.26
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.308CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=info | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[67] : Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.735CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[79] : Setting max total connections (500)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.736CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[80] : Setting default max connections per route (100)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.803CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[79] : Setting max total connections (500)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.803CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpClientFactory[80] : Setting default max connections per route (100)
time=2016-06-14T06:51:36.804CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=start | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[240] : [ckan-sink] Startup completed
```

The agent config:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = ckan-sink
cygnusagent.channels = ckan-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = papel_club
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 5
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules_hist.conf
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

# ============================================
# OrionCKANSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel

# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink

# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = true

# true if lower case is wanted to forced in all the element names, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_lowercase = false

# the CKAN API key to use
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = 436fffc8-b397-478a-92fd-bbc5ffaf8269

# the FQDN/IP address for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = ckan-demo.ckan.io

# the port for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 80

# Orion URL used to compose the resource URL with the convenience operation URL to query it
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = localhost:1026

# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = column

# enable SSL for secure Http transportation; 'true' or 'false'
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false

# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100

# timeout for batch accumulation
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 60

# number of retries upon persistence error
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10
```

I think the problem is in this line in the config

```
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
```

But the [doc](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/ngsi_agent_conf/index.html) said it is ok any ideas?

How should I update the 0.13 version? should I uninstall cygnus 0.13 and do it on a clean flume? will be released a yum install package like with the cygnus 0.13 version?

Comment: Is the `cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file under `/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/` really empty?

Comment: exactly the file is empty. Don't know why. I edit my post with the first compilation result

Comment: It seems you don't have enough disk space, or memory, or the permissions are not correct when writing the jar... it must be something like that what is avoiding the `cygnus-common` jar is created.

Comment: I have give the fiware cygnus folder and subfolder 777 rights and run man as root. I have enough disk and ram (i don't know if the assigned to maven is enough - 512mb ). I'm still getting the error don't know why. Will try another linux machine.

Comment: Please, try using different values of memory settings.

Comment: @frb I just edited the post with new questions. Changing the memory don't work. I have to compile it in another linux machine.

Comment: Ummm, most of the related questions in SOF point to a memory problem... Let's try to run with `-X` option, that enables the debug mode of Maven. Please, post the relevant parts.

Comment: I run with -X but the document was hudge I will try to send you it later. I found out another thing if I compile without giving it more ram it compiles, but  if i do again with more ram it terminates as seen in here http://pastebin.com/d0DucSJj

Comment: The maven debug log https://proyectos.hackshine.com/cygnus/outn.log . I'm using java 8

Comment: It seems Maven has not finished... there is no final "Build sucess" or "Build error" message.

Comment: @frb solved using 3gb of ram as said in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807381/packaging-cygnus-common-results-in-an-empty-jar but have the same issue described in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840296/cygnus-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-telefonica-iot-cygnus-interceptors i described it to on my post as a part of the update

Comment: From Cygnus 1.0.0, you must use `NGSIGroupingInterceptor` instead of `GroupingInterceptor`.

Comment: Perfect I will add a summary of this comments as an answer. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved compilation problems using 3gb of ram as said in here [Packaging cygnus-common results in an empty jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807381/packaging-cygnus-common-results-in-an-empty-jar)

Upgrading is just following the [compile as sources doc](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html) but using the cygnus 0.13 path as the flume folder (/usr/cygnus)

The error with the Grouping interceptor is solved as said by @frb:

> From Cygnus 1.0.0, you must use NGSIGroupingInterceptor instead of
>   GroupingInterceptor