# Packaging cygnus-common results in an empty jar

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to install cygnus-common following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680260/how-to-compile-cygnus-1-1-0-from-sources) but the creation of the cygnus-common jar (incl. dependencies) always results in an empty jar. Apache-Flume installed without any issues. I've tried increasing the memory for the Maven JVM as per the guide but this hasn't helped.

```
~/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common$ mvn clean compile exec:exec 
assembly:single
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cygnus-common 1.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/cygnus/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to /home/cygnus/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) @ cygnus-common ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/cygnus/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common/target/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Killed
```

Here's the resultant file

```
~/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common$ ls -lrth target/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 3 cygnus cygnus 4.0K Jun 13 14:57 generated-sources
drwxrwxr-x 3 cygnus cygnus 4.0K Jun 13 14:57 classes
drwxrwxr-x 2 cygnus cygnus 4.0K Jun 13 14:57 archive-tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cygnus cygnus    0 Jun 13 14:58 cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680260/how-to-compile-cygnus-1-1-0-from-sources) was asked before with no resolution documented. The only suggestions given for that question was either lack of disk space, memory or permissions. Disk space is definitely not an issue, I have increased the memory for the Maven JVM and the user has the correct permissions.

**EDIT:**

So I ran the `mvn compile` in debug mode as suggested by @frb and it was memory issue

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 257024000 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2827), pid=48868, tid=140567873734400

  [1]: http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html#section3 "guide"
```

using `top` I was able to see that the memory usage was over 70% when the process got killed. The system has ~1.7Gb which is well above the stated [requirements](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/hw_requirements/index.html), and it is a 64bit system.

I had the system memory increased to 3Gb and the build succeeded so perhaps the hardware requirements should be updated?

Comment: Now I can see a Maven log (the other issue did not post it), could it be the JVM has not enough memory? Try [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError) link.

Comment: Thanks for replying @frb I had tried increasing the memory already as I mentioned above but it didn't solve the problem. I tried again just in case but the jar is still empty unfortunately.

Comment: Ummm, most of the related questions in SOF point to a memory problem... Let's try to run with `-X` option, that enables the debug mode of Maven. Please, post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the system memory to 3Gb fixed this issue and the jar was created successfully.